# javascript: google maps like experience in viewing div

Tags: javascript

There is a div that is bigger than the window size. I'm looking for such a library or a way to view div element like it is in Google maps (drag and scale with scroll). There are other elements in this div

P.S. I don't use jquery and don't want to

Comment: Can you give us a sample of what you have tried? What is the content of the large div like? I would recommend using SVGs if you want to scale the content without losing fidelity.
The drag feature would be relatively straightforward to implement (even without SVG). You can listen for `touchstart` or `mousedown` and related events and adjust the positioning/scroll offsets (based on whether you use absolute positioning) of the large div.

Comment: This div is 2000px by 2000px. There are other divs inside of it, that you can drag

Comment: This question already has an answer here https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/730779/230633